# Unable to parse and compare float in Scalatest after using JavaTokenParsers

Tags: scala, scalatest

In playing with Scala's combinator parsing framework, I came across the following problem when parsing floating point numbers:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.junit.ShouldMatchersForJUnit
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class SandboxSpec extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchersForJUnit {
  "A java token parser" should "parse a float" in {

    class Parser extends JavaTokenParsers {
      def realValue: Parser[Float] = floatingPointNumber ^^ {
        s => s.toFloat
      }
    }

    val p = new Parser()
    val result = p.parseAll(p.realValue, "5.4") match {
      case p.Success(x, _)     => x
      case p.Failure(msg, _) => fail(msg)
    }

    result should equal (5.4f plusOrMinus 0.0001f)

  }
}
```

This test produces the following error:

```
5.4 did not equal FloatTolerance(5.4,1.0E-4)
```

I'm not sure if it's the parser code producing something not float-like (though, looking at it with the debugger, it's clearly a Java Float), or if it's an issue with the ScalaTest matcher.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ScalaTest `equal` always means `==`, thus object equality. Thus, your code does not succeed because `5.4` is not equal to an instance of `FloatTolerance`.

To correct your test case use `be`, which is overloaded to take an instance of `FloatTolerance`:

```
result should be (5.4f plusOrMinus 0.0001f)
```

Btw, your code throws a warning:

> match may not be exhaustive. It would fail on the following input: Error(_, _)

To eliminate it choose `case p.NoSuccess(msg, _) =>` instead of `case p.Failure(msg, _) =>`

Comment: I can see where I went wrong here, though the documentation (http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers) causes some minor confusion here, since it recommends `equals` for an exact comparison, and `be` for the the `plusOrMinus` case.